# Nginx domain matching for TLD wild card

Tags: nginx, tld

I'd like to catch dev.*.sometld in NginX.

But NginX doesn't accept:

```
server_name dev.*.sometld;
```

And I don't want to do:

```
 server_name dev.*;
```

How can I match exactly "dev.*.sometld"?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't. You must do `*.dev....` instead.

Comment: Possible with regexp, but I don't see why `dev.*` is not good for you?

Comment: I don't want to use `dev.*` because that could catch domain dev.sometld.
Could you help me with the regexp? This is the closest that I've got to: `~^(?<dev>\w+)\.\*\.sometld$;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `server_name ~^dev\..*\.sometld$;`